# Parsing MySql Query with Reserved Word

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, parsing

Below code is for getting sum of quantity from MySql database.

'**deger**' returns with **{"SUM(quantity)":75}**

I want to take '**75**' from that object.

I have tried;

```
deger.SUM(quantity)
```

Since SUM is reserved word, it does not work.

```
connection.query("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM report WHERE fabrika = ? ", fabrika, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              var row = rows[i];
              var deger = JSON.stringify(row)
              console.log("**********************************");
              console.log("Possible Quantity: " + deger); //Possible Quantity: {"SUM(Quantity)":75}
              console.log("**********************************");
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated for yourself?  Change your query to use an 'as'  SELECT SUM(quantity) as quantity FROM ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gview.

Adding '**as quantity**' after SELECT, solved the problem.

```
connection.query("SELECT SUM(quantity) as quantity FROM report WHERE fabrika = ? ", fabrika, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
              var row = rows[i];
              var deger = JSON.stringify(row)
              console.log("**********************************");
              console.log("Possible Quantity: " + deger); //Possible Quantity: {"SUM(Quantity)":75}
              console.log("**********************************");
            }
          }
        });
```